# Simple question on the gauge function

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose that $X$ is a real vector space and $K$ is a convex subset of $X$ that contains the origin as an interior point of $K$, i.e., if $y\in X$, then there exists an $\epsilon_{y} >0$ such that
\begin{align}
ty \in K
\end{align}
for each real $t$ such that $|t|<\epsilon_{y}$. Show that if $x\in X$ is such that
\begin{align}
p_{K}(x) := \inf \{a>0|\tfrac{x}{a}\in K\} < 1,
\end{align}
then $x$ is an interior point of $K$, i.e., if $y\in X$, then there exists an $\epsilon_{y} >0$ such that
\begin{align}
x + ty \in K
\end{align}
for each real $t$ such that $|t|<\epsilon_{y}$.

My attempt: Since $p_{K}(x)<1$, we know that there exists a real number $a$ such that $0<a<1$ and
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{a} \in K.
\end{align}
Let $y\in X$. Since the origin is an interior point of $K$ there exists an $\epsilon_{y/(1-a)} >0$ such that
\begin{align}
t\frac{y}{1-a} \in K
\end{align}
for each real $t$ such that $|t|<\epsilon_{y/(1-a)}$. Since $K$ is convex we conclude that
\begin{align}
x + ty =  a \cdot \frac{x}{a} + (1-a) \cdot t\frac{y}{1-a} \in K
\end{align}
for each real $t$ such that $|t|<\epsilon_{y/(1-a)}$.

Does this look OK?

Comment: if $y\in X$, then there exists an $\epsilon_{y} >0$ such that 
\begin{align}
x + ty \in K
\end{align} : This does not prove that $x$ is an interior point. $\epsilon_y$ has to be independent of $y$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I use the definition of Peter D. Lax. Page 21 in his book on functional analysis.